# Выборка уникальных значений из MySQL

Tags: php, база-данных, mysql

Есть цикл, который меняет в БД MySQL имя на его `ID` из другой таблицы, но он работает на так, как нужно. Дело в том, что когда в БД встречаются рядом стоящие одинаковые записи (с одинаковым именем), то в базе обновляется всё и со одинаковым `ID`. Подскажите, где нужно подправить.

```
result = mysql_query("SELECT * `id_thing`  FROM `clothes`") or die(mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {  echo $row['id_thing']."<p>";  $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `tatu` WHERE `name`='".$row['id_thing']."' ") or die(mysql_error());  $myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result2);  echo $myrow['id']."<p>";  if($myrow['id']>0)  {   $result3 = mysql_query("UPDATE `clothes` SET `id_thing`='".$myrow['id']."'") or die(mysql_error());  }  else  {   echo "OK";  } }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct
```

- выбор уникальных значений

  select ....... group by `FIELD_NAME`
- выбор всех значений, но с группировкой  при выводе. То бишь, в этом случае их можно отфильтровать.

Comment: knes, Всё равно с одним ID всё добавляется, в данном случае уже последний ID из перебора